# Loop through ID and array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I have a checkout page that has some **item numbers** that show up on the page. I got all the item numbers and put them into an array. Each item on the page has an ID that increases by one **(#item1, #item2)** and class of **.item**.

If the item matches an **item number** in the array then I need to hide or remove an edit link with the class of **.edit-item** and a Save For Later link with the class **.save**.

I went with children so as to not affect other items on the page but I am running into issues with the code below. Any advice on how to proceed? I feel like I might have approached this wrong.

```
var selectors = ["NMF19_N5N5K", "NMF19_N5N5E", "NMF19_N5N5N", "NMF19_N5N5L", "NMF19_N5N5C", "NMF19_N5N5F", "NMF19_N5N5M", "NMF19_N5N5Q", "NMF19_N5N5P", "NMF19_N5N5D"];
    var idNumber = 1;
    var i;

for (i = 0; i < selectors.length-1; i++) {

    if (jQuery('#item' + idNumber)) {
        jQuery('#item' + idNumber + ':contains(' + selectors[i] + ')' ).children()[8].children[0].children[2].children[1].children[0].children[2].remove();
        jQuery('#item' + idNumber + ':contains(' + selectors[i] + ')' ).children()[8].children[0].children[2].children[1].children[3].remove();
        idNumber++;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add `idNumber = selectors[i];` at the very top of your for loop.

Comment: It is wrong for sure, your feeling is good :) Please post the part of HTML output where we can see the structure of the item, together with buttons you wanna hide.

Answer (score 0):

While having the actual HTML would have been helpful the description along with the code provides an idea of what HTML structure might be. Before providing a solution I will like to go over a few jQuery related things.

1. `$` is an alias of `jQuery`. `$` is used in most example code online.
2. The expression `jQuery(selector)` will always be truthy. To check if an element exists use `jQuery(selector).length`. The expression results in `0` if the element does not exist, the count of matched elements otherwise.

The solution is to loop through all `.item` elements with [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Then use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find any of the item numbers from the list in each row. If found then remove the edit and save action buttons.

```js
var itemNumbers = ["NMF19_N5N5K", "NMF19_N5N5E", "NMF19_N5N5N", "NMF19_N5N5L", "NMF19_N5N5C", "NMF19_N5N5F", "NMF19_N5N5M", "NMF19_N5N5Q", "NMF19_N5N5P", "NMF19_N5N5D"];

// Loop through all .item elements
$('.item').each(function() {
  // An item reference, Ex: #item1, #item2 ...
  var $item = $(this);
  // The item row as text
  var itemAsText = $item.text();

  // Check if this item row contains an item from the itemsNumbers list 
  var matched = itemNumbers.some(function(itemNumber) {
    return itemAsText.indexOf(itemNumber) > -1;
  });

  if (matched) {
    // Look for the edit and save elements within $item and delete them
    $item.find('.edit-item').remove();
    $item.find('.save').remove();
  }
});
```

```css
ol {
  width: 400px
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li id="item1" class="item">Item 1 - NMF19_N5N5N <button class="save">Save</button><button class="edit-item">Edit</button></li>
  <li id="item2" class="item">Item 2 - Custom5<button class="save">Save</button><button class="edit-item">Edit</button></li>
  <li id="item3" class="item">Item 3 - NMF19_N5N5F <button class="save">Save</button><button class="edit-item">Edit</button></li>
  <li id="item4" class="item">Item 4 - Custom4 <button class="save">Save</button><button class="edit-item">Edit</button></li>
  <li id="item5" class="item">Item 5 - NMF19_N5N5D <button class="save">Save</button><button class="edit-item">Edit</button></li>
</ol>
```